# "Achieved this qualification since reaching the age of 17?"

Tags: sentence

Can someone explain this sentence? It's asking me about graduating secondary school. Thank you.

Comment: Context. It is not optional. I have known people who would utter something like this and mean "did you finish before you reached the age of 17?" even though no native speaker would normally understand this phrase that way. The concepts of _until_ and _since_ can be quite hard for some ESL-speakers.

Answer (score 1):

At some point between turning 17 and the present time, they achieved this qualification. It can be that the author meant to say something else but that's what this phrase means as written. It's also not a complete sentence so I'm not sure who the subject is.